# Creating a Hierarchy of dependencies from two columns in Excel/Power BI

Tags: excel, powerbi, pivot-table, hierarchy, topological-sort

I am working with Power BI for the first time. I have two columns: node1 and node2.
The column relationship is that Node 1 depends on Node 2.
Node 1 can have dependencies on multiple nodes.
Also, Node 2 can be dependent on multiple nodes and so on.
I want to create level wise dependency columns such as Level 1 (Root Dependency) -> Level 2 -> Level 3 -> Leaf Level for all nodes.

```
Node 1 | Node 2 | Outcome
A          B      D | C | B 
A          C      D | C 
B          C      D | C
C          D      D
```

I have tried creating data model with PowerBI to include function as follows:

```
PATH(Column 2, Column 1)
```

However it does not allow to have multiple values for one Node.
Can anyone please suggest way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no recursion functionality in DAX, you may consider to leverage Power Query recursion capability to create additional column to work out the dependency path of each `Node 2`. You can refer to this repository for the coding which should be exactly what you are looking for : https://github.com/synru/powerquery.

It has a custom function for doing this. Good luck: https://github.com/synru/powerquery/blob/main/fn_Dependency_Chain.pq